# Remove border from an image inside an anchor tag

Tags: html, image, css

So.. I'v added a bottom border to my anchor tags, to make them stand out. But I have some images that are also warped around with anchor tags. The thing is, I don't know how to remove the border from the image.

**Please note that I'm using WordPress and I can't edit how links and images are displayed**

This is my CSS Code:

```
.entry-content a {
padding:0 3px;
color: #104273;
border-bottom:2px solid #104273;
}
```

And my question is, that is there any way to make something like this?

```
.entry-content a img {
border:none;
}
```

So it only removes the border from the images with links?

http://codepen.io/andornagy/pen/sdzBq

Comment: can you give us a fiddle to see or check?

Comment: Well, yes, it is possible and your code looks ok. Have you tried and what was the result ? Note that you shouldn't use `!important` by design... and you actually don't need it in that case as your second selector has greater specificity than the first one, the `!important ` is redundant.

Comment: I added the a codepen demo

Comment: .entry-content a:not(a img) {
padding:0 3px;
color: #104273;
border-bottom:2px solid #104273;
}

Comment: What you are doing is adding a border to a tag and then trying to remove border from img tag by using !imporatnt. which is not going to work. You have use classes for a tags containing images because there is no way to identify in CSS which parent tag contains which child tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is that you're styling the anchor tag and then trying to overwrite that style on an `<img>` tag, which doesn't actually have the style being applied to it, but rather it's parent.

If you don't want to use Javascript, you can wrap your text in the links in a `<span>` tag and style that span instead of the anchor itself.

HTML

```
<a href='#'><span>This is a blank Link</span></a>
<a href='#'><img src="..."></a>
```

CSS

```
a {
    padding:0 3px;
    color: #104273;
    text-decoration:none;
}
a span {
    border-bottom:2px solid #104273;
}
```

Here is a fiddle of it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/xVSA9/

**UPDATE**

Ok, here is a solution using jQuery's [parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) selector.

```
$('img').parent('.entry-content a').css("border-bottom", "none");
```

Leaving your CSS/HTML the same, this should work just fine.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GeR85/

Comment: The border is still the for the image. And I can't really add the span tags since I'm using WordPress. What would be the JS way?

Comment: And is there any way to remove the background color on hover ?

Comment: @And0r1995 Yes, do the same as the code above, only add the `:hover` pseudo-selector to the CSS selector

Answer (score 0):

presuming you're HTML looks as follows:

```
<div class="entry-content">
    <a href=""><img src=""/></a>
</div>
```

the image is a direct child of the anchor so you can use the 'direct child' selector in CSS which is a more than symbol.

```
.entry-content>a>img{}
```

I like to use organised lists when making menus because it's in the name. They're organised lol.

```
<ol id="menu">
    <li>
        <a href=""><img src=""/></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="">This is a blank link</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="">Another link</a>
    </li>
</ol>
```

CSS

```
img{
    border:1px solid #000000
}
ol#menu{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0px;
    padsding:0px;
}
ol#menu>li{
}
ol#menu>li>a{
    display:block;
    padding:10px 5px;
    font-size:20px;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000000;
}
ol#menu>li>a>img{
    border-bottom:none;
}
```

Avoid using `!important`.

Answer (score 0):

There you go... :)

the HTML :

```
<div class="entry-content">
<a href="#">test</a>
<a href="#">
    <img src="https://www.google.co.il/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
</a>
</div>
```

the CSS:

```
.entry-content a:not(a img) {
padding:0 3px;
color: #104273;
border-bottom:2px solid #104273;
}
```

the jsFiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/3RJ3Q/2/